# What does ?ref=rua on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Every once in a while I get a entry in my stats that say that the user accessed our site from Facebook with ?ref=rua as a query string -- I have looked in all the obvious locations as well as on their documentation:

http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Ref

Nothing seems to show what ?ref=rua refers to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the 'Recently used Apps' unit which appears on a user's Timeline (example attached)
[image: sample of the unit]

By the way, that's not official documentation you linked to, it's a third-party site